# asp.net mvc - present content based upon user id and role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am working on a asp.net mvc application. I require the ability to limit what a user can see on a specific page based upon there username & role. The username is to be the windows authentication name in the format of DOMAIN\Username and will be assigned to one or more roles of which will reside in a SQL database.

Based upon the above, I need a way so that a user can only see information that is relevant to their role. For example, in the image bellow there is 3 images that represent potential applications the user might have access too.Two of them are green and one is blue. Consider these to be the ROLEs. How can I make sure that users belonging only too blue cannot see the two green. 
[image]

The username in the top right is being detected via the `@User.Identity.Name` functionality in Razor. I was thinking it would be as simple as detected that from the current user and then query the database for roles. How would we then limit the content based upon those roles?

Bonus Question, I want an administrative component that allows those with the admin role to assign new users roles by querying the organizational accounts. Is there a simple way to provide a search feature of that?

**HTML (index view)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Project Name</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
           <a href="#">Project Name</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

which would look something like the following...
[image]

**Shared _Layout**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - blah blah blah</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("IHS Data Manager", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">@User.Identity.Name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>blah blah blahMorningStar Partners LP</p>
    </footer>
</div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/IDM")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Data Model**
[image]

Comment: How does user login to your application? Could you show the authentication and authorization code?

Comment: In the long run, it would probably be better to switch to the Claims and Permissions model, and check if a user has a permission to execute something or see some data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question how the user can or can not see a specific content based on a specific role you can use something like below - *For admin role*:

```
if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Project Name</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
    </div>
}
```

If this is not exactly what you need let me know, so I can give you any other idea!

Comment: This might be what im looking for. Where is "IsInRole" checking? What does that configuration look like.

Comment: It is checking in database for a specific role name for current user. You can debug it and see what happens. To test it you can add a role to a user from a controller or manually from db.